# How to update view state in Android?

Tags: android, android-view, android-configchanges

I need to refresh text in `TextView` (`TextView` with `id`) on configuration change. `Android` saves its state on configuration state because it has `id`. But I want to update text (because language may be changed).

Comment: So you want to update Text, whenever user selects different language from setting ?

Comment: @Kedarnath yes, you understood me correctly.

Comment: Create a Broadcast that receive the event whenever you change language from setting, and once you return the event, change the text according :)  Since you are changing the language, you need to create multiple String.xml based on the language.

Comment: But I set text in xml via `android:text="@string/string_id"`.

Comment: I just checked but there is no such event :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem in this way... add a static boolean to the class containing the view you want to refresh, and change this variable to true when opening settings... then, update your onResume method in this way:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
super.onResume();
if (changed == true) {
    this.recreate();
    changed=false;
    }
}
```

this will force recreation on the view.